# Do we need to publish image topic for "Gazebo camera sensor"?

Tags: ros, gazebo, camera, topic, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/AddingSensorsToPR2) and [another similar solution](http://answers.ros.org/question/11965/using-camera-sensor-in-gazebo/) to add an camera for my simulation. Basically what I did is adding one "Gazebo camera" block in my robot urdf.

However I could find the image topic using "rostopic" after I upload my "robot_description". So does it mean that "[robot state publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_state_publisher)" will NOT publish the image topic automatically?

If yes, could I publish the image topic with, e.g. [image transport](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_transport/Tutorials/PublishingImages)?

Thanks!

Yuquan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47392/do-we-need-to-publish-image-topic-for-%22gazebo-camera-sensor%22?/) by [yuquan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2801/yuquan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2012-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[robot_state_publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_state_publisher) only publishes kinematic information (joint frames), not sensor information. If you are using the [gazebo_ros_prosilica](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_gazebo_plugins#gazebo_ros_prosilica_node) plugin, then that plugin should be publishing the camera topics.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yuquan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2801/yuquan/) on 2012-11-04**:
Thanks for the quick reply! I'll try it.